# Javascript - sum and multiply each row

Tags: javascript, loops, sum, row

Currently I have code that automatically sum all input quantities (see image below).

[Click for Image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UKyo.png)

[Click for jsFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/CDaHW/2)

**But I want to make another field that automatically calculates total costs depending on each row price and entered quantity.** (currently field appearing with 0)

I would really appreciate if someone could help me to do this. I have also made hidden inputs for prices, so it would probably be easier to work with, similar to quantities.

For loop will be required, right? Have no further ideas..

My current JS code for quantities sum:

```
$.fn.sumValues = function() {
    var sum = 0; 
    this.each(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(':input') ) {
            var val = $(this).val();
        } else {
            var val = $(this).text();
        }
        sum += Math.round( ('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 0 );
    });
    return sum;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.count_field').bind('keyup', function() {
        $('input.total_field').val( $('input.count_field').sumValues()  );
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<td class="total">
  <input type="text" class="prices_total_field" readonly>
</td>
<td class="total">
  <input type="text" class="total_field" readonly>
</td>
```

PHP

```
echo '
<input type="hidden" class="price_count_field-'.$i.' price_count_field" value="'.$data['price'].'">
<input class="count_field-'.$i.' count_field" type="text" name="count-'.$i.'">
';
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML? Maybe even a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as this is a client-side only issue.

Comment: Added. Hope this helps. Code doesn't work in jsFiddle or I don't know how to use it there.
Also added classes with loop $i, this should help if making js loop. I don't know..

Comment: Added working code in jsFiddle. Check that. But remember that prices and quantity fields should by like rows - see image link above.